# Syntax error trying to pass arguments to postgreSQL command with poscopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

The line of code below gives this error:

""'test_1'"
syntax error at or near "'test_1'"
LINE 1: select exists(select 1 from 'test_1' where ID = 'd5b3e5f6-45...

I'm trying to pass the arguments "test_1" (table name) and a certain ID 'd5b...', however I think they're being inserted with the quotes, resulting into an error. Is there an easy way to fix this? I would like to keep using the 2nd argument to execute.

```
cursor.execute("select exists(select 1 from %s where ID = %s)", [sub_root.tag, ID]
```

Comment: See https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql

Comment: cursor.execute("select exists(select 1 from %s where ID = (%%s))" % sub_root.tag, ID)

doesn't seem to work either

Comment: No, don't do that, it's insecure and vulnerable to SQL injection. The link above explains how to do it safely, and ends with a safe approach that uses `sql.SQL()`.

Comment: cursor.execute(sql.SQL("select exists(select 1 from {} where ID = %s").format(sql.Identifier(sub_root.tag)), ID))

syntax error at or near "d5b3e5f6" (the ID)

to me it looks like I'm doing exactly the same thing as they suggest, am I missing something?

Comment: That's missing the closing `)` inside the query. Also the parameters should be a list, i.e. `[ID]` instead of `ID`. Try changing it to `cursor.execute(sql.SQL("select exists(select 1 from {} where ID = %s)").format(sql.Identifier(sub_root.tag)), [ID])`

Answer (score -2):

You can use f-strings for string interpolation like this:

```
cursor.execute(f"select exists(select 1 from {sub_root} where ID = {ID})")
```

Note: If **ID** variable is of type string then place it in between the single quotes like this **'{ID}'**

Comment: Don't do this, it's insecure and vulnerable to SQL injection.